# Get first UTF-8 char from string and save in DB

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8, zend-db

I have a problem with inserting a letter that is not an `A-Z` char.
For example:

`$fullTag = 'świat';`

A `'letter'` should contains `ś`

```
$data = array(
    'full_tag'  => $fullTag,
    'count'     => 1,
    'letter'    => $fullTag[0],
);
```

But when I execute `$table->insert($data);`, it inserts me as `letter` an empty string.

If I set instead of `$fullTag[0]` a static letter `ś` - it works fine.

`letter` column is `utf8_polish_ci` `char(1)`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of $fullTag[0], you may want to use a multibyte substring function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php .. these mb_* functions are aware of multibyte encodings, $fullTag[0] may only give you one byte.

Comment: I tried with `mb_strcut($fullTag, 0, 1, 'UTF-8')` but it does not work.
`mb_substr` works - strange.......

Do you know why ?

Thanks Jaanus ! :-)

Comment: `mb_strcut()` works exactly as substr() or the indexer-access, but, if the last byte appears to be truncated, it simply omits the character. In your case `mb_strcut()` detects that cutting your string at byte 1 will result in a malformed byte-sequence - therefore it omits the last character which is the only character in your case.